# Create a list of all file names and their file extension in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a dataset using pd.DataFrame to store file name and file extension of all the files in my directory. I eventually want to have two variables named Name and Extension. The name variable will have a list of file names and the extension variable should have a file type such as xlsx, and png.

I am new to python and was only able to get to this. This gives me a list of file names but I don't know how to incorporate the file extension part. Could anyone please help?

```
List = pd.DataFrame()

path = 'C:/Users/documnets/'

filelist = []
filepath = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        filelist.append(file)
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext('/path/to/somefile.xlsx')
        filepath.append(file_extension)


List = pd.DataFrame(flielist, filepath)
```

Also, for this part: os.path.splitext('/path/to/somefile.xlsx'), can I leave what's in the parenthesis as it is or should I replace with my directory path?

Thank you

Comment: Do you already have a list of `filenames` and `file paths`?

Comment: No, I'm creating everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:/Users/documnets/'

filename = []
fileext = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
    name, ext = file.split('.')
    filename.append(name)
    fileext.append(ext)

columns = ["Name", "Extension"]

data = [filename, fileext]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns).transpose()
```